# How to find the PMF from $G_Z(s)=\frac{\lambda+\mu-\sqrt{(\lambda+\mu)^2-4\lambda\mu s}}{2\lambda}$

Tags: probability

How to find the PMF from the probability generating function

$$ G_Z(s) = \mathbb{E}(s^Z) = \frac{\lambda+\mu-\sqrt{(\lambda+\mu)^2-4\lambda\mu s}}{2\lambda} \quad ? $$

The textbook says:<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qn3o.png)</sup>

> Expanding the series, for all $\lambda$ and $\mu$ we obtain
>
> $$ \mathbb{P}(Z = n) = \frac{1}{2(2n-1)}\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^n, \qquad n \geq 1. $$

Can't seem to get this result to pop out by "expanding the series". Is anybody able to help me with the calculation?

Comment: For $\lambda+\mu\ge 0$, $\sqrt {(\lambda  + \mu )^2  - 4\lambda \mu s}  = (\lambda  + \mu )\sqrt {1 - \frac{{4\lambda \mu s}}{{(\lambda  + \mu )^2 }}} $. Now use the generalised binomial series for $\sqrt{1+x}$ with $x= - \frac{{4\lambda \mu s}}{{(\lambda  + \mu )^2 }}$.

Comment: Brilliant got it now. Thanks so much

Comment: Nitpicking: It should be PMF (probability **mass** function), not PDF (probability **density** function). Also, I took the liberty to edit your question so it looks better and is visible from search engines. Hope this is also to your liking :)